# Embedding contents of a folder in a web page

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I'm building a super simple CMS in PHP, and have what's probably a simple question...

I'm storing my news in .txt files (I know it should be a database, I'm just not focusing on that stuff for now...) and need to display these files on a page (news.php). It should basically print the contents of each file in reverse alphabetical order, for example:

Files:

> 12-11-11.txt
>   12-12-11.txt
>   12-13-11.txt
>   12-14-11.txt

Display:

> Contents of 12-14-11.txt
>   Contents of 12-13-11.txt
>   Contents of 12-12-11.txt
>   Contents of 12-11-11.txt

I'd like to wrap each post in something like `<div class="article"></div>`.

I'm very new to PHP so a good code example would be lovely. I'm storing my files like this:

news page: /news.php
news files: /edit/news/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (glob("/edit/news/*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Tried it, got this error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /f5/(redacted)/public/news.php on line 18` I think it's the `glob` bit because that's the only uncolored bit, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, this looks like it's only going to show the file name and size of the file, but I need the actual contents of the file to be displayed.

Comment: Figured it out, just needed to remove the `/` before `/edit/news/*.txt`, works almost perfectly now :)

Comment: @Rev: Glad to be of help :) Note that if glob finds nothing then it'll return false, so it might pay to assign the result of your glob to a variable, check it isn't false, then foreach it.